# I have windows xp media edition on my PC and i need to free up space

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, performance-tuning

I have a 80 gb hard drive.Can i delete some system volume information files? Also should i delete program setup files after setup is complete?

Comment: Whatever you do don't connect that machine to the internet.  XP has many known security flaws that can allow attackers to take complete control of the machine.  And since it is firmly end-of-life those flaws will never be fixed.

Comment: afraid it's a little to late.I'm online Every day but 95% of my time is spent on facebook playing casino games.

Comment: If your computer seems slow then it is likely busy sending out millions of spam emails at a time.  Using your resources for free so some spammer can get the one in a million sucker response from them.

Comment: Use windows disk cleanup to clean up system files and all but last restore point (or all restore points).  Then clean you temporary internet files via your browser.  Finally use a program like "WinDirStat" to find and manually address any "bloated" directories.

Answer (score 1):

Don't delete System volume files, it's critical. 
Yes, you can delete program setup files if it's unnecessary. Delete all unnecessary files so you can have more space to install your software.